# Excel list an array in one row (without duplicate)

Tags: arrays, excel

In Excel, I have an array from A1 to P30 filled with names. Some cells have the same name (duplicate).
Is there a formula possible to list all the content of this array in one single column (on another sheet)? This list must gather only unique name (no duplicate).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also this for a formula solution https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1966-excel-extract-unique-values-from-multiple-columns.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Function Unique(strRng As String) As Variant()

    Dim Arr() As Variant
    ReDim Arr(0)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Duplicated As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    j = 0
    Set rng = Range(strRng)

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        Duplicated = False
        If c.Value <> vbNullString Then
            For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
                If c.Value = Arr(i) Then
                    Duplicated = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            If Not Duplicated Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(j)
                Arr(j) = c.Value
                j = j + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    Unique = Arr

End Function 'Unique
```

### Update

Seems you insist to using a function. Easy. Create a **User Defined Function** (UDF) as below:

```
Function Unique(rng As Range) As Variant()

    Dim Arr() As Variant
    ReDim Arr(0)
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Duplicated As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    j = 0

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        Duplicated = False
        If c.Value <> vbNullString Then
            For i = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
                If c.Value = Arr(i) Then
                    Duplicated = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            If Not Duplicated Then
                ReDim Preserve Arr(j)
                Arr(j) = c.Value
                j = j + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    Unique = Arr
    ' OR
    'Unique = Application.Transpose(Arr) 'Use this when you want transpose your range from row to column or back.


End Function 'Unique
```

How to use the function?

Note that this is an `array form` function.

1. Write second code in VBA.
2. select the range you want to return your unique values. (*In each sheet and each part of column*)
3. Write `=Unique(A1:P30)` in formula bar and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>  from keyboard. (Dont press <kbd>Enter</kbd> only)

Now, you have a formula that return you unique values of a range as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a Collection or Dictionary to check for duplicates.

In this example I use an ArrayList

```
Sub ProcessNames()
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim list As Object
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each v In .Range("A1:P30").Value
        If Not list.Contains(v) Then list.Add v
    End With

    '1 Dimensional 0 Based Array which will span 1 Row
    v = list.ToArray

    '2 Dimensional 1 Based Array that will span 1 Column
    v = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(v)
End Sub
```